# UITableViewController reloadData not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableViewController that keeps acquire for data from database.
And I want to display the data every time it changes.

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSArray *)myArray{
    if (_myArray!=myArray) {
        _myArray=myArray;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

From debugging, I noticed when reloadData get called, numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
is called. 
But cellForRowAtIndex is not touched.
If I move my tableview, cellForRowAtIndex is called.
How can I reloadData programmatically?

Comment: This is the right way, though it's more correct to use `_myArray = [myArray copy]`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: does numberOfRowsInsection return a number of rows >0?

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things, that you're properly initializing `_myArray`, and the value that `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning by doing an NSLog. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only be called if `numberOfRowsInSection` is greater than 0.

Comment: pretty sure no one mentioned an issue with initializing _myArray in the above comments, and there's a good chance that's the problem.